# Placing a flat box layer on the bottom

Tags: layers

I'm trying to place a flat box layer on the bottom of every objects but how?  The layer goes on top of them instead.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by saying "a flat box layer"? And placing it on the bottom of every object? Which object, the cube? And what exactly are you doing to try to place it? The only thing I see above the cube is a selected plane but I don't know what you tried to do so far...

Comment: I tried to draw a flat box underneath the cube as the floor.  Instead of underneath it, it appeared above it.  Any clue how to draw a flat floor underneath the cube?

Comment: I recommend watching a few tutorials for getting the basics like moving stuff around. Blender's official website points you to some good resources: https://www.blender.org/support/ . Moving stuff is one of the most basic features in Blender, so if you don't know how to do that, chances are you are missing another  essential functionality even for a start. You can obviously use BSE for whatever questions no matter how simple, but it will just be way easier and quicker to learn the basics from video tutorials.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a Plane not a Cube for that! It's where it is because it's created where you have the 3D cursor. Firstly move the cursor to the world origin with Shift-C and move you cube up to sit on the origin by selecting it and using G Z 0. Then add your Plane Shift-A > Plane (and take note of @MartynasŽiemys comment above!)

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution by typing:
Then add your Plane <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Plane*

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your answer? Basically it just says to add a plane (not even in your own words, just copied from the comment by @JohnEason above), but since you already had a plane (or is it a flat cube?) in your question's screenshot I wonder how this is a solution to your problem... I thought the problem was **where** the object is placed, not **which** object is added.